# Context dependent syntax highlighting in vs code, sublime or atom

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I'm developing a language to write down mathematical proofs for proof checking. (To be more accurate: it is a language to write down derivations in [Post canonical systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_canonical_system))

Is it possible to create syntax highlighting for VS Code, Sublime Text or Atom which will do something like this:

[image]

So I'm asking for context dependent syntax highlighting. Only the "declared" variables should be highlighted (until the next variable declaration).

Of course, with a custom lexer in [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) it is possible. But the TextMate-like grammars seem to be too limited. If this is the case: Is there a code editor that can use something like Pygments to highlight code?

Remark:

1. It isn't important what happens if one variable is an initial segment of another.
2. The semantical content of the example is nonsense, of course.

Comment: I don't know any details about the other editors you mentioned, but this is not possible in Sublime Text; the syntax system it uses (even the one that is enhanced over the TextMate style `tmLanguage` syntax variant) allows context sensitivity in the form of extra rules that apply in contextually defined situations, but those rules need to be pre-defined in the syntax ahead of time.

Comment: Essentially it's possible in both, Atom and Visual Studio Code. Both are based on [Electron](https://electronjs.org/), so in a nutshell they work and can be programmed like browser. You can use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM, e.g. insert syntax-highlighting classes for dynamically determined strings. But this is far beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question. You are invited to come back with specific problems along the way. The Atom [discussion forum](http://discuss.atom.io) is a friendly community that probably can help you.